# How to compare each row from table with all rows?

Tags: mysql, join

Im using mysql.

Compare each row with all left rows from this table and select the ID and timestamp where HEADING is between -15 < Heading (from last row) < +15 AND -10 < timestamp (from last row) < +10.

```
myTable
id
heading (In degrees)
timestamp (in seconds)
```

Eg. of the 1st table rows:

```
1 - 50 - 133324565
2 - 12 - 133324565
3 - 10 - 133324565
5 - 220 - 133324565
6 - 35 - 133324565
10 - 10 - 133324565
11 - 15 - 133324565
12 - 22 - 133324565
16 - 168 - 133324565
```

As you see, ID's are not sequential, so I can't do this right?

```
SELECT T1.id,T1.heading,T2.id,T2.heading
FROM mytable as T1, mytable as T2
WHERE T1.id > T2.id -1
AND (T1.timestamp > T2.timestamp -10 OR T1.timestamp < T2.timestamp +10)
AND (T1.heading > T2.heading -15 OR T1.heading < T2.heading +15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.id,T1.heading,T2.id,T2.heading
FROM mytable as T1, mytable as T2
WHERE T1.id > T2.id AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT T3.id FROM mytable as T3 WHERE T3.id<T1.id AND T3.id>T2.id)
AND (T1.timestamp > T2.timestamp -10 OR T1.timestamp < T2.timestamp +10)
AND (T1.heading > T2.heading -15 OR T1.heading < T2.heading +15)
```